# Selecting top layer element with .hover()

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to select the top layer element on hover?

For example, let's say I have two divs. In the first one the top layer will be span.myText1, but if I hover off from span but remain in div, the div will be the top layer that I hover over.

Similar example applies to the second div, except it has more layers.

I would like to .addClass('outline ') to the top layer ONLY.

**CSS**

```
.outline {
    outline: 5px solid #66ff66;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="divs">
    <span class="myText1">some text</span>    
</div>

<div class="myDiv2">
    <div style="width:300px">   
       <span class="myText2">some text <button value="myButton"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think .hover() is the way to go but not sure how.

```
$(myTopLayer).hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('outline');                
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('outline');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update - misunderstood your question; my previous answer was doing the opposite of what you wanted!

On hover in, add class to the current element and remove from all of its parents and on hover out, remove class from the element and add to the immediate parent div using `first()`

note that the code is using generic `div` and `span`, you might want to use specific ones so that this doesn't happen to all `div` and `span` on the page.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7eNzB/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $("div,span").hover(

    function (e) {
        $(this).addClass('outline').parents().removeClass('outline');
        e.stopPropagation();
    },

    function (e) {
        $(this).removeClass('outline').parents("div").first().addClass('outline');
    });
});
```

---

Previous answer -

In the function just check if there is a parent div or not before applying the style. If a parent DIV exists, add style to the last parent (top most) else apply style to the current element.

You might want to change the selector in `$("div").hover(...)` to a specific parent DIV property.

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7eNzB/)

```
$(function () {
    $("div").hover(

    function () {
        if ($(this).parents("div").size() > 0) {
            $(this).parents("div").last().addClass('outline');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('outline');
        }
    },

    function () {

        if ($(this).parents("div").size() > 0) {
            $(this).parents("div").last().removeClass('outline');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('outline');
        }

    });


});
```

Comment: There is a .parent() function - it returns the first parent - eliminating the need for .parents().first()